# Reformulating absolute-value objective functions to take derivatives

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, karush-kuhn-tucker

Given the following optimization problem: 
$\min_{w_t} |w_t - w_{t-1}|^T\gamma$ 
s.t. $w_t^T\phi \leq 0.15$ 
where $w_t, w_{t-1}, \phi, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$ and $\phi > 0, \gamma > 0$

I am trying to find closed-form solution for this problem. However, before I attempt to write the Lagrangian and proceed to use the KKT conditions to solve for the solution, I believe I **need to reformulate the optimization problem (as we cannot take derivatives of the absolute-value function required for the stationarity condition of KKT)**.

Any help, guidance or reference on how I can proceed to reformulate the problem and subsequently solve for the analytical solution will be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So $w_t$ is a variable but $w_{t-1}$ is an input parameter?

Comment: Are the inputs $\gamma \geq 0$?

Comment: @RobPratt yes, $w_{t-1}, \gamma, \phi$ are input parameters. Only $w_t$ is a variable to be optimized over. Do you happen to have any suggestions on how I can proceed to solve for $w_t$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers, yes, $\gamma > 0; \phi > 0 $. I have included that in the question. Please let me know if there are any other clarifications I can provide. Any help towards solving for $w_t$ is very much appreciated.

Comment: you can use standard tricks to reformulate this as a linear optimization problem

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. I am however not able to proceed to solve for $w_t$ after reformulating this problem as a linear optimization. Please refer to my comments on RobPratts answer below. Please feel free to add a new answer/comment with any help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce variable $x\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ to represent the absolute value, and the resulting linear programming problem is to minimize $x^T \gamma$ subject to
\begin{align}
x &\ge w_t - w_{t-1} \\
x &\ge -w_t + w_{t-1} \\
w_t^T\phi &\le 0.15 
\end{align}

In standard form, minimize $\gamma^T x$ subject to
\begin{align}
x - w_t &\ge - w_{t-1} \\
x + w_t &\ge w_{t-1} \\
-\phi^T w_t &\ge -0.15 
\end{align}

The dual problem is to maximize $-w_{t-1}^T\lambda+w_{t-1}^T\theta-0.15\psi$ subject to
\begin{align}
\lambda + \theta &= \gamma \\
-\lambda + \theta - \phi \psi &= 0 \\
\lambda &\ge 0\\
\theta &\ge 0 \\
\psi &\ge 0
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, introduce variables $x^+, x^-\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, and minimize $(x^++x^-)^T \gamma$ subject to
\begin{align}
x^+ - x^- &= w_t - w_{t-1} \\
x^+ &\ge 0 \\
x^- &\ge 0 \\
w_t^T\phi &\le 0.15 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. To follow up, if using the first approach, the optimization problem becomes: $min_{x, w_t} x^T\gamma$ s.t $x \geq w_t - w_{t-1}, x \geq -w_t + w_{t-1}, w_t^T\phi \leq 0.15$. Hence, the Lagrangian now becomes, $L(x,w_t, \lambda, \theta, \psi) = x^T\gamma - \lambda(x - w_t + w_{t-1}) - \theta(x + w_t - w_{t-1}) - \psi(0.15 - w_t^T\phi)$. With that the KKT conditions are then, Stationary Condition: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = \gamma - \lambda e - \theta e = 0 [1]; \frac{\partial L}{\partial w_t} = \lambda e - \theta e +\psi\phi = 0  [2] $

Comment: Considering the interesting case where the 3rd condition is active, $w_t^T\phi = 0.15 [3]$, I am unsure how I could use [1], [2], [3], to solve for $w_t$. 

Any help will be very much appreciated. Please feel free to edit your answer with any hints/helps.

Comment: thank you for updating your answer with the duals. It is still not clear to me how I am able to solve for $w_t$ using the duals. I recently posted [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4091029/solving-optimization-with-absolute-value-objective-function-using-kkt-conditions) discussing more explicitly on how we could solve for $w_t$. Please feel free to provide your answer there. I am going to accept your answer for this question as this question was mainly posed for reformulation techniques.